# Where to ask for recommendations selecting a IRC client?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, irc

I would like to ask the following questions:

1. Are there any IRC programmes (local or web), plugins, features, etc. that allow for making rich-text formatting, either directly or through markup (e.g. [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown))?
2. If not, then is there a way to give an IRC programme said capability?

But I'm not sure which site to ask on: StackOverflow or SuperUser.

On the one hand, I'm asking a question that may involve a markup language, so StackOverflow seems most appropriate for that. On the other hand, I'm asking about poweruser-esque capabilities of applications, so in that case SuperUser would be most appropriate.

---

**Note**: I'm not asking about any particular StackExchange or StackExchange-related feature or channel or whatever. I'm asking about IRC in general.

Comment: I'd suggest you inspect the available webclients for irc. If none of them hasn't already your wanted feature, you could easily implement it yourself.

Comment: @gnat: Yeah, it seems to be a duplicate. My mistake.

Comment: @ott: How could I implement it myself?

Comment: That would answer my 2nd question.

Comment: Which is, @gnat, not actually a duplicate, AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

#### But I'm not sure which site to ask on: StackOverflow or SuperUser.

Neither. Software recommendations are off-topic on both.

You can try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).